# conditional statement for running a function?

Tags: javascript

i have some js which runs when its on mobile. When the browser is above 768 this function shouldnt run. also is there a way to revert an append method in vanilla js?

```
if (window.innerWidth < 768 ) {
    mobileNav();
} else {

}
```

Comment: Where is your `append()` method ?

Comment: mmm, why dowsnt work, please put it into context

Comment: revert an append? Well you just use the `.remove()` method on the element you just added with `.append()`

Comment: You're basically asking: "why is this code not working but without any code"

Comment: suggestion: use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to conditional add and remove your mobile menu

```js
var breakpoint = matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)")
var message1 = document.createElement('p')
var message2 = document.createElement('p')

message1.innerText = 'the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide'
message2.innerText = 'the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide'

function render() {
    if (breakpoint.matches) {
      // the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide
      // add mobileNav()
      message2.remove()
      document.body.append(message1)
    } else {
      // the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide
      // remove mobile nav
      message1.remove()
      document.body.append(message2)
    }
}

render() // render initial
breakpoint.onchange = render // as well on changes
```